# Curve fit minimizing the sum of the deviation

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I'm fitting a curve taking the smaller sum of deviations for each parameter tested, the smaller sum returns me the parameter that gives the best fit. Here is the algorithm for a test $f(x, parameter)$:

```
function fit(function:function, list:sample_y, list:x_values, list:parameter_values):
    sums = []
    for each parameter in parameter_values:
        y = function(x_values, parameter)
        deviations = sum(abs(sample_y - y))
        sums.push(deviations)
    end for
    smaller_deviation = min(sums)
    parameter_index = sums.index_of(smaller_deviation)
    return parameter_values[parameter_index]
end function
```

This method is working. I can minize the error giving a nice band of parameters.

I'd like to know whether is valid fit data in this way and, if It's valid, this method has a name?

Obs.: I'm avoiding using levemberg-maquardt and least squares methods...

Comment: This can be called the Least Absolute Difference method (minimizing the SAD metric). Anyway it seems to be an approximate variant, as the minimization algorithm looks rather simplisitc. I would recommend at least the Nelder–Mead simplex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Translation:**

There is some function $f : A \times B \to C$ where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are some sets of objects, where $C$ supports addition, subtraction, taking the absolute value and determining a minimal element.

- $x$ is a countable subset of $A$.
- $p$ is a countable subset of $B$, called parameters.
- $y$ is a countable subset of $C$, called samples.

For all $i$ that index $p$, the values
$$
D_i = \sum_j \left\lvert y_j - f(x_j, p_i) \right\rvert
$$
are calculated and from this the minimum
$$
d = \min_i D_i
$$
The result is 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
p_k
$$
with
$$
k = \argmin_i D_i
$$
**Interpretation:**

Let $n$ be the number of different $p$ values, then this leads to the calculation of $n$ vectors $\tilde{y}_i = (f(x_j, p_i))$ which each have a distance $D_i$ to the sample vector $y$ in the [1-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm):
$$
D_i = \lVert y - \tilde{y} \rVert_1
$$
The algorithm returns the parameter $p_k$ associated to a closest vector $\tilde{y}_k$ to $y$.

Comment: exactly this! Then It is valid, right? Is there a name for this method?

Comment: According to [this paragraph](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methode_der_kleinsten_Quadrate#Geschichte) Laplace had the idea to sum up the absolute values of the errors. I do not know a name. Gauss rather added the squares of the errors, thus using the Euclidean norm (or 2-norm) instead. So it is certainly not bad, but using a different norm might be better depending on how your errors are related to your parameters. Gauss justfied his choice by some statistical reasoning [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem).